# python unittesting: applying a test on an external file

Tags: python, unit-testing, text, append

I have written a short script to test if the first words from a text file I have saved in a different folder all start with a capital letter. however, i realized the self...append method does not work correctly. Here is the code:

```
import os
import unittest

DIRECTORY= os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
text_file = os.path.join(DIRECTORY, '/data/text_folder')

class TestAugmentation (unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestAugmentation, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.file = os.path.join(text_file, 'test.txt') 
        self.text = [] # the list of the augmented text

    def test_reader(self):
        with open(self.file) as f:
           data = f.readlines()
        for element in data:
           self.text.append(element.strip())

    def test_capitalization(self):
        for entry in [entry for entry in self.text]:
            self.assertTrue(entry.split[0].isupper(), 'The sentence starts with a lowercase')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

in particular i would like to append the content of the test.txt file to the self.text list, so I would be able to use it in all other functions to come same as the test_capitalization function. however, the append does not seem to work.

the test.txt file contains sample sentences like below, and i expect to see an error because not all sentences start with a capital letter.

'The weather is nice'

'the first chapter is fine'

'Her name is Lucy'
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code I am assuming that each sentence is on a separate line.
There are a couple of things in your code that are problematic.
First, a matter of style: setting up a unit test is usually done in `setUp`, not in `__init__`.
Second, `test_reader` is not a test, but part of the setup, or can be done in the test itself. Tests that depend on each other is bad practice, also test functions that don't test anything.

Your test does not work, because `test_reader` is executed *after* `test_capitalization` -- `unittest` orders tests alphabetically by default.

So, here is an example for a working version, provided you have one sentence per line as assumed in your code:

```py
class TestAugmentation(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.file = os.path.join(text_file, 'test.txt')

    def test_capitalization(self):
        for line in open(self.file):
            line = line.strip()
            if line:  # ignore empty lines
                self.assertTrue(line[0].isupper(),
                                f'{line} starts with a lower case letter')
```

or if you want to read the file in the setup, because you need it in other tests, you could also write:

```py
class TestAugmentation(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        file_path = os.path.join(text_file, 'test.txt')
        self.text = []
        for line in open(file_path):
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                self.text.append(line)

    def test_capitalization(self):
        for line in self.text:
            self.assertTrue(line[0].isupper(),
                            f'{line} starts with a lower case letter')
```

Note that in this case the file is read before each test.
If you to read it only once in your test class, you can use `setUpClass` instead:

```py
    def setUpClass(cls):
        file_path = os.path.join(text_file, 'test.txt')
        cls.text = []
        for line in open(file_path):
            ...
```

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed explanation and for your help. it was very informative